# Google Cloud speech to text v2 gives error decoding_config: required oneof field 'decoding_config' must have one initialized field

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

This is my request:

POST TO: [https://us-central1-speech.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{SECRET}/locations/us-central1/recognizers/_:batchRecognize](https://us-central1-speech.googleapis.com/v2/projects/%7BSECRET%7D/locations/us-central1/recognizers/_:batchRecognize)

```
{
  "processingStrategy": "DYNAMIC_BATCHING",
  "files": [
    {
      "uri": "gs://{SECRET}/transcribes/1704048500788"
    }
  ],
  "recognitionOutputConfig": {
    "inlineResponseConfig": {}
  },
  "config": {
    "languageCodes": [
      "he-IL"
    ],
    "model": "chirp",
    "autoDecodingConfig": {}
  }
}
```

The operation created, and this the response of the operation:

```
{
  "gs://{SECRET}/transcribes/1704044534650": {
    "error": {
      "code": 3,
      "message": "The RecognitionConfig proto is invalid:\n  * decoding_config: required oneof field 'decoding_config' must have one initialized field"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "totalBilledDuration": "0s"
    },
    "transcript": {},
    "inlineResult": {
      "transcript": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to follow the exact refrence here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/v2/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.recognizers#RecognitionConfig

But still does not work. I also tried to set manually the decoding options but still does not work.
When I set the decoding manually got exactly the same issue.

Here is the body where I set it manunally:

```
{
  "processingStrategy": "DYNAMIC_BATCHING",
  "files": [
    {
      "uri": "gs://{SECRET}/transcribes/1704048774055"
    }
  ],
  "recognitionOutputConfig": {
    "inlineResponseConfig": {}
  },
  "config": {
    "languageCodes": [
      "he-IL"
    ],
    "model": "chirp",
    "explicitDecodingConfig": {
      "audioChannelCount": 1,
      "encoding": "LINEAR16",
      "sampleRateHertz": 16000
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: The request part looks right to me. How are you sending the request, exactly? (It looks odd because that looks like a google.longrunning.Operation...)

Comment: Sending using nodejs, axios. But same error when sending using Postman. curl or any other HTTP library

Comment: But are you really sending something with `"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v2.OperationMetadata"` as part of it? If so, that's really not what you should send as a request. The request is *just* the `BatchRecognizeRequest` object.

Comment: I updated the question with the exact body of the request. (Before I copy the body from the response)

Comment: Right - that makes more sense (and unfortunately means I can't help - it looks okay to me).

Answer (score 0):

I used this https://console.cloud.google.com/speech/recognizers/list to generate a recognizer. Then I used this https://console.cloud.google.com/speech/transcriptions/list to do a transcription. Next, I click on the copy code button at the top menu bar to get the nodejs code and it works.

const fullPath = getStorage().bucket().file(`${uid}/${id}.m4a`)
.cloudStorageURI.href;

```
console.log(`Full path: ${fullPath}`);

const audioFiles = [{ uri: fullPath }];

// Full recognizer resource name created from `https://console.cloud.google.com/speech/recognizers/list?hl=en&project=${projectid}`
const recognizerName =
  `projects/${projectid}/locations/${location}/recognizers/${name-of-recognizer-created}`;

const recognitionConfig = {
  autoDecodingConfig: {},
  model: "chirp",
  languageCodes: ["auto"],
  features: {
    enableWordTimeOffsets: false,
    enable_word_confidence: false,
  },
};

const outputPath = {
  inlineResponseConfig: {},
};

const request = {
  recognizer: recognizerName,
  files: audioFiles,
  config: recognitionConfig,
  recognitionOutputConfig: outputPath,
};

const callBatchRecoqnize = async () => {
  const [operation] = await client.batchRecognize(request);
  const [response] = await operation.promise();
  return response;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to use the REST API and not the client library.